# Odoo 11 - assign value to variable on <select> tag in Web Template

Tags: html-select, odoo, qweb, odoo-11

I want to assign value to a variable when a user picks a choice in a dropdown in Odoo 11 Web Template. So when a user has done clicking the dropdown then a value will be assigned with a value accordance to user pick

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
   <select class="form-control" id="university_id" name="university_id">                
      <t t-foreach="universities" t-as="university">
        <option t-att-value="university.id"><t t-esc="university.name"/><t set="var_univ" t-value="university.name"/></option>                      
      </t>
   </select>
</div>
```

I want to set a value in `var_univ` variable with the name of the university. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try to append value on that variable at the time of onclick event. Select class of clicked element and on that class write your value code.

Comment: is there an example for this in the default module? I have no idea how to custom qweb templating.

Answer (score 0):

please try with following :

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="university_id" name="var_univ">                
       <t t-foreach="universities" t-as="university">
          <option t-att-value="university.name">
            <t t-esc="university.name"/> 
          </option>                      
       </t>
   </select>
</div>
```

Make sure above div tag is in Form View with action.

Thanks !